# No option to download language

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, language

I want to add a new language (Japanese) to Windows 10 Enterprise 1607.

So I go into Settings / Time & Language / Region & Language and click on Add a language, then add Japanese.

It says "Searching Windows Update" for a few seconds, then nothing.

When I click on Japanese and then Options, I expected to see an option to download the language, but the only options in here ate to change or add a keyboard.

Any idea why there's no option to download the language?

*Edit*

I do not have the single language edition of Windows 10

*Edit 2*

If I click on "Additional date, time, & regional settings" I get brought to a control panel screen with similar options. I now click on Language which shows me my two languages - and then Options beside the Japanese one, it brings me to a screen with Display language and Input Method info...

Under "Windows Display Language" it says "Checking Availability" for a few seconds, then "Connect to the internet to check for language packs".

However, I am connected to the internet - I can browse the web & stuff, no problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate if you have a Single Language edition of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this was that:

Since I had been doing some debugging of another application at the time, I had set the time on my device to be about a year in the future.

The Windows language update obviously doesn't like this (although it doesn't tell you that), but setting my system back to the correct date and time fixed the problem.